# Is CSRF protection needed on each single form?

Tags: forms, symfony, fosuserbundle, csrf-protection

I know this is a basic question: do I need the CSRF protection on each single form in my application, or just in the login page?

I'm implementing a website with FOSUserBundle in Symfony2.6.1. I noticed that the login form is protected against CSRF but all the other forms aren't (or at least that's what I get from here):

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $this->buildUserForm($builder, $options);

    $builder->add('current_password', 'password', array(
        'label' => 'form.current_password',
        'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
        'mapped' => false,
        'constraints' => new UserPassword(),
    ));
}
```

Notice that this function is inside the protected area, as it allows you to change your profile.

Apart from the FOSUserbundle the question is wider.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You really need a CSRF protection on all forms that can modify or access sensible data when the user is fully authenticated.

Symfony provides this protection by default on all your forms.

You can desactivate it like that:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'csrf_protection'   => false,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Symfony's form documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#csrf-protection):

> The good news is that, by default, Symfony embeds and validates CSRF tokens automatically for you. This means that you can take advantage of the CSRF protection without doing anything.

It's always a good idea to have CSRF protection in your forms, and thankfully Symfony handles it for you without you having to add extra code for it.

Comment: I read that line but I thought it was too good to be true. So even if I manually create a form using "$form = $this->createFormBuilder()->getForm();" and then adding each of the fields I need, *without*adding*the*security*token* Symfony will do it for me?

Comment: Yup it will add it for you automatically.  When you do `{{ form_rest(form) }}` it adds any of the fields you didn't explicitly state, which will then have the CSRF.